# Error in Gradle Build Script: Issue with 'device_info_plus' Dependency

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

**I'm encountering an error while trying to build my Android project, specifically related to the 'device_info_plus' dependency. The error is located in the 'build.gradle' file of the 'device_info_plus' package. I've included the error message below for reference:**

```
Build file 'C:\Users\techn\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\device_info_plus-9.0.3\android\build.gradle' line: 27
A problem occurred evaluating project ':device_info_plus'.
...
```

## Here's the content of the 'android/build.gradle' file at line 27:

```
group 'dev.fluttercommunity.plus.device_info'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    namespace 'dev.fluttercommunity.plus.device_info'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

**Expected Outcome:**
I'm aiming to successfully use the 'device_info_plus' package in my Flutter project without encountering this error.

**Additional Information**:

Android Studio version: Giraffe | 2022.3.1
Flutter version: Flutter 3.10.6
Dart version:  Dart 3.0.6
Operating System: Windows 11 Home Single Language

**Error Stack Trace:
**
ask me if needed plz... because of lengthy code.